# Why do I keep getting Heroku 503 Error while in Production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, axios

I'm trying to get my website to function properly after being deployed on Heroku. It is essentially a Youtube Clone; you sign up for an account and then you can upload videos. Locally, it runs correctly, but I constantly receive a 503 Error; this time while uploading a video. The thumbnails of the video do not load, see image below

[image]

The code is at this repo: https://github.com/aladin94/clone2.

The heroku website: https://afternoon-sea-81365.herokuapp.com/

The Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "youtubeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "youtube-clone",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.14.1",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "backend": "nodemon index.js",
    "frontend": "npm run front --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend\" \"npm run start --prefix client\""
  },
  "author": "aladin feratovic",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

The Heroku logs:
[image]

Not sure if the code for the routes (get/post) are not tuned properly for Production? I've attached the mongoDB database (whitelisted the ip too) and structured my files accordingly for Heroku.

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: 500-series HTTP errors are server-side. You need to look at your logs, e.g. with `heroku logs`.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Your `metadata` is undefined. Why that might be, we can't say without more information.